# Ionic 4 and Angular 2 ( IOS swipe back gesture will trigger the NgOnInit&&ionViewWillEnter&& ionViewDidEnter)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

```
 ionViewWillEnter(){
      this.getVoucher();
}

   ionViewDidEnter(){
      this.getVoucher();
}

   ngOnInit(){
      this.getVoucher();
}


  public async slidePage(navigate){

     let options : NativeTransitionOptions = {
      direction:'left',
      duration: 400,
      slowdownfactor: -1,
      iosdelay: 50,
      androiddelay: 50,
      fixedPixelsBottom:0,
      fixedPixelsTop:0

     }
    this.nativePageTransitions.slide(options);
    this.navCtrl.navigateRoot(navigate);
  }

  public async goBack(navigate){

      let options : NativeTransitionOptions = {
        direction: 'right',
        duration: 400,
        slowdownfactor:-1,
        iosdelay:50,
        androiddelay: 150
      }
     this.nativePageTransitions.slide(options);
     this.location.back();

  }
```

When the swipe back gesture trigger, back to the home page. How to prevent it from refresh the data and show the loaded data directly? For example, home -> voucher page, and from voucher page back to home page ( do not refresh homepage data)

Comment: use only 'ngOnInit' so in this case if you back to the page your data not reload

Comment: or you can check `if(voucherData == null){ this.getVoucher()}` wrap in inside if condition.

Comment: Hi these methods are not working. Maybe is it any problem with my navigate and back function make the ngOnInit always trigger? But the IOS swipe back function that used is the ionic framework build in 1. However, thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Found the problems should be navigateForward to navigate to another page. navigateRoot will destroy de previous page.